# How to mock CloseableIterator in a test?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, mockito

In my implementation I'm grabbing data from ElasticSearch via [ElasticsearchTemplate#stream()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.html#stream-org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery-java.lang.Class-) which returns `CloseableIterator<>`.

I'd like to mock this method by doing:

```
List<MyClass> foo = new ArrayList<>(); // and then I add some elements
when(mockTemplate.stream(any(SearchQuery.class), eq(MyClass.class))
 .thenReturn(foo.iterator());
```

but `iterator()` returns `Iterator<MyClass>` which is not `CloseableIterator<MyClass>` and I have no clue how to cast it or find a workaround.

Comment: Excellent question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.springframework.data.util.CloseableIterator.CloseableIterator` from Spring  and `java.util.Iterator` from JDK are close enough interfaces :  indeed `CloseableIterator` has `Iterator` as parent interface.
Which means that you can substitute a `Iterator` by a `CloseableIterator` but not the reverse : what you need.
While you cannot return an `Iterator` in your mock record, you can still convert an `Iterator` to a `CloseableIterator`.  Which is not very hard thank to method delegation while it still requires a small amount of boilerplate.

Example :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery;
import org.springframework.data.util.CloseableIterator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockCloseableIteratorTest {

  @Mock
  ElasticsearchTemplate mockTemplateMock;

  @Test
  void foo() {
    List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>();
    // and then I add some elements
    Mockito.when(mockTemplateMock.stream(any(SearchQuery.class), eq(String.class)))
           .thenReturn(createCloseableIterator(foo.iterator()));

  }

  private <T> CloseableIterator<T> createCloseableIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return new CloseableIterator<T>() {
      @Override public void close() {
      }

      @Override public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
      }

      @Override public T next() {
        return iterator.next();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: ahh I was so close, I was almost there - just generated `CloseableIterator` but didn't know how to link it with my `Iterator` instance; passing an iterator and using its method `hasNext()` and `next()` inside the CloseableIterator is brilliant, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For those working on Kotlin, following will be the syntax for createCloseableIterator method:

```
    private fun <T> createCloseableIterator(iterator: Iterator<T>): CloseableIterator<T>? =
    object : CloseableIterator<T> {
        override fun close() {}
        override fun hasNext() = iterator.hasNext()
        override fun next() = iterator.next()
        override fun remove() {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@MockK
private lateinit var closeableIterator: CloseableIterator<YourClass>

fun() {
        every { closeableIterator.hasNext() } returnsMany listOf(true, false)
        every { closeableIterator.next() } returnsMany listOf(YourClass())
}
```

For another Kotlin version that worked for me.